# Download document & Load Image(png, jpeg), pdf, doc, etc in WKWebView swift

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, alamofire, wkwebview

I am using Alamofire to download documents from a url, the document can be image, pdf or doc etc.
Below code is used to download using Alamofire and saving in the document directory and loading in webview.

```
func saveToDocumentDirectory(BillUrl: String) {
        let manager = Alamofire.Session.default
        let fileName = (BillUrl.components(separatedBy: "/").last) ?? ""
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

        let destinationPath: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }
        manager.download(BillUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil, to: destinationPath)
            .downloadProgress { (progress) in
                print("Temporary URL: ")
                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
        }
        .response { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let pathUrl) :
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                print(pathUrl as Any)  //pathUrl = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C651C521-31A7-4512-A393-6A94442472A0/Documents/1_DlatFlsbZ1fJSs-_aIJmlg_1588075057_13.png

                self.displayAlert(path: pathUrl ?? URL(string: "")!)

            case .failure(let error) :
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                print(error)
                self.alert(message: "Something went wrong while proccessing your request", title: "Alert!")
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func displayAlert(path: URL) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "file downloaded at \(path)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in  
            let webViewVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewVC") as! WebViewVC
            webViewVC.webUrl = path
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewVC, animated: true)
        })
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

below code for webview class

```
class WebViewVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var webUrl = URL(string: "")

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: webUrl!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 600.0))
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width , height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        view = webView
    }
}
```

The pdf file is loading properly in webview, but the image is not loading properly in webview and the top part of image hiding behind the navigation bar.
[image]
[image]

I created the outlet of WKWebView and also adding it to `self.view.addSubview(webView)` but every time it get crashed at `webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)` 
I don't know what to try next. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the `WKWebView` by setting the frame so that it does not overlap with `UINavigationBar`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

   var WKwebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
               let userContentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
               let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
               conf.userContentController = userContentController
               WKwebView = WKWebView (frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 60 ), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
               WKwebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
               WKwebView.uiDelegate = self
               WKwebView.scrollView.bounces = false
               WKwebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
               view.addSubview(WKwebView)

                var request : URLRequest!
                let LOGINURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRy76.png";
                let url : URL = URL(string: LOGINURL as String)!
                request = URLRequest (url: url);
                WKwebView.load(request)

    }
}
```

**Output** : [Output without overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv1Kp.png)

Comment: thanks, it's working but showing blank screen on iPad Air with iOS version 12.4.3

Comment: are you trying to load pdf file from url ? It worked for me in iPad Air, 13.3 version.

Comment: I'm loading pdf and image(png format) both. it loading in iPhone and iPad simulators, 13.0 version but not on iPad Air, 12.4.3

Comment: Are you getting any issues in console ? Try to load the PDF file in safari browser . If it is loading there , then we need to inspect in wkwebview .

Comment: The PDF file and Image is loading in safari. I'm sharing by build using diawi to tester to test.

Comment: Try to debug WKWebView in , https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/